# MySQL Update value to unique for specific month/year combination

Tags: mysql, locking

I have table **records** containing: **id, year, month, number, value**

When record is created **number** is set to **NULL**.

Later when record is registered I need to create unique **number** for that record, that will be unique for specific **year** and **month** combination and should be incremented from last **number** existing for this month. At the same time someone else may try to do it and most probably will choose the same incremented number as me. I need to avoid duplicates if they are created at the same time.

If no number exist for given month it shall be started with 1.

Number values may repeat in the table but not for the same year/month combination.

I though of doing it this way:

1. lock the table
2. sort the existing values descending (for given month/year) and get first one
3. increment it and update specific record
4. unlock table

but I wonder if there is any more clean and elegant way to solve it?  I would like to avoid locking the table for too long, or risk it to be left locked in case of problems on app side.

Regards.

Test data as requested:

```
CREATE TABLE RECORDS (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `year` int(4), `month` int(4), `number` int(4), `value` int(4), PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
INSERT INTO RECORDS (year, month, number, value) VALUES
(2019, 10, 1, 100),
(2019, 10, 2, 200),
(2019, 10, 5, 300),
(2019, 10, 3, 400),
(2019, 10, 4, 500),
(2019, 10, 6, 600),
(2019, 10, NULL, 700),
(2019, 10, NULL, 800),
(2019, 10, NULL, 900),
(2019, 11, 1, 100),
(2019, 11, NULL, 200),
(2019, 11, NULL, 300),
(2019, 11, 2, 400),
(2019, 11, 3, 500),
(2019, 11, NULL, 600),
(2019, 11, 4, 700),
(2019, 12, 1, 100),
(2019, 12, 2, 300),
(2019, 12, NULL, 200),
(2019, 12, NULL, 500),
(2019, 12, NULL, 600),
(2019, 12, NULL, 700),
(2019, 12, NULL, 800);
```

Fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d4Dfs5zcBUU1X95TaaHbNx/0#&togetherjs=93fntrtw0y

Comment: Why do people set these obstacles for themselves? Just store an id and move on.

Comment: I can not disregard requirements that I have been given to. Numbering format is strict...

Comment: Oh well I hope you are charging appropriately. - your approach seems as good as any.

Comment: MariaDB-10.3 has [SEQUENCEs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-sequence/)

Comment: But I think you're confusing issues of data display storage and retrieval with those of data display.

Comment: I just think storing derived data is the wrong approach.. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d4Dfs5zcBUU1X95TaaHbNx/0#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these are the basic steps to most efficiently update according to your needs.

1. Create a unique index on `year`, `month`, `number` (in that order) to prevent dupes and allow filtered locking.
2. Use `FOR UPDATE` when incrementing the number to prevent other transactions from reading the rows during the update while only locking the rows with the corresponding year and month, not the entire table.

```
BEGIN;
SELECT MAX(NUMBER)
FROM RECORDS
WHERE YEAR = ? AND MONTH = ?
FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE RECORDS
    SET NUMBER = ?
    WHERE YEAR = ? AND MONTH = ?;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I am looking for. `CREATE TABLE RECORDS (id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, year int(4), month int(4), number int(4), value int(4), PRIMARY KEY (id),  UNIQUE KEY unique_number (year,month,number));` and then `BEGIN;
SELECT @current := MAX(number) FROM RECORDS WHERE year = ? AND month = ? FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE RECORDS SET NUMBER = ifnull(@current, 0) + 1 WHERE year = ? AND month = ? AND id = ?;
COMMIT;`